# Comparator nesting models in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

If I use a comparator on a backbone collection, would I be able to nest the models that have the same attribute into a div? Examples

```
// My dummy json
[{name: 'Robert', team: 'Redskins'},{name: 'Aaron', team: 'Packers'},{name: 'Kirk', team: 'Redskins'}]
```

Then here is my collection.

```
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'data/players.json',
    comparator : 'team'
});
```

I see this is cool, because in my rendering view, I see the models are listed in order by teams, example.

```
<div>
    <li>Robert</li>
    <li>Redskins</li>
</div>
<div>
    <li>Kirk</li>
    <li>Redskins</li>
</div>
<div>
    <li>Aaron</li>
    <li>Packers</li>
</div>
```

Just in case here is the code for my view.

```
var Player = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.app',
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        var players = new Players();
        players.fetch({
            success: function(players) {
                var template = _.template($('#appTemplate').html(), {players: players.models});
                self.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now to the meat, whats the cleanest way to group the teams into a nest, example below.

```
<div class="Redskins">
    <div>
        <li>Robert</li>
        <li>Redskins</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li>Kirk</li>
        <li>Redskins</li>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Packers">
    <div>
        <li>Aaron</li>
        <li>Packers</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535122/wrap-items-in-backbone-collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really think of any way to accomplish that without parsing/manipulating your data.  You could hijack the toJSON() method or add a new method altogether.  For example:

```
var Players = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'data/players.json',
    comparator : 'team',
    toJSON: function() {
        var team,
            index = 0,
            grouped = [],
            raw = _.clone(this.attributes);

        _.each(raw, function(element) {
            var thisTeam = element.team;
            if (thisTeam != team) { // create new grouping
                grouped[index] = {
                    team: thisTeam,
                    players: []
                }
                grouped[index].players.push(element.name);
                index++;
            } else { // use existing grouping                
                grouped[index].players.push(element.name);
            }
        });

        return grouped;
    }
});
```

Caveat: this is untested code for illustration only.  Anyway, this code will give you some JSON like:

```
[
    {
        team: "Packers",
        players: ["Aaron"]
    },
    {
        team: "Redskins",
        players: ["Robert", "Kirk"]
    }
]
```

Here is a sample Handlebars template:

```
{{#each this}}
<div class="{{team}}">
    <div>
    {{#each players}}
        <li>{{this}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I took a nap. Okay interesting, but with this how would I set HTML to be wrapped this is where I am so confused, I don't know how to get a group of items inside a wrapper div.

Comment: What are you using for templates?  I'll update my answer to show the template code for Handlebars, which is what I use.  But it should be easily adapted to Underscore or whatever you use.

Comment: Id like to get into handlebars, but I am using underscore because I am brand spanking new to backbone, I get it now, but struggle with going beyond into advanced waters. I appreciate the effort, it really means alot!

Comment: Okay thanks I can translate that into underscore, so that toJSON method remains intact correct? Could I just write my json like your result?

Comment: Haha, no worries.  This was all Greek to me as well just a few months ago.  The first month is the worst because there are so many new concepts to get your head around.  Still have so much to learn but at least now I don't feel like a total idiot.

Comment: Yeah finally someone can relate, I totally agree that 1 month is about the time it takes to get comfortable and it's quite a tough month. Backbone is really fun and I see the power in it, which is why I keep pushing forward. So, I can iterate `this` then access those attributes, nice! What about the toJSON, could I just rewrite the json?

Comment: With my solution, you would override the native toJSON() method with the one above, so no, the original toJSON() doesn't remain intact.  If you want to keep it intact, then just rename the method above to something else.  The usage of this method assumes that the collection is sorted by team otherwise the grouping logic doesn't work.  So I would keep your JSON as you have it, then use the method above to post-process the collection before handing it to your template.  That also allows you to add new items to the original collection and everything will get re-grouped when you need it.

Comment: ok cool, im excited definitely gotta 1+ you, going to play with it, most likely be back with a green check! The thing I like about this overall it seems pretty minimal, which is always nice.

Comment: You know, it's been so long since I've used Underscore templates but that does seem in the ballpark at least.  I've also seen the syntax `<% _.each(this, function( model ){ %>`

Comment: make sure you add a comment after `team: thisTeam`